# Find strange TAR archive format

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I have some file that can be extracted with `tar`:
`tar -tvf attachment.tar`
But when I test it with `file` I have this result:
`attachment.tar: uuencoded or xxencoded text, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

The first bytes of this file are `begin 644 RST.0486.20220814-0300.tar` 
That follows by:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M0U4P-#@V+D%)6%-C86XN,C`R,C`X,30M,#,P,"YT>'0`````````````````
M````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M`````````````#$P,#8T-"``,#`P,#`P(``P,#`P,#`@`#`P,#`P,3(P-S4S
M(#$T,C<V,3$V-C0T(#`Q-34R,0`@,```````````````````````````````
M````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M``````````````````````````````````````````!U<W1A<@`P,')O;W0`
M````````````````````````````````````<WES=&5M````````````````
M```````````````````P,#`P,#`@`#`P,#`P,"``````````````````````
M````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
M```````````````````````**BHJ*BHJ*B`@1&%T92`@*BHJ*BHJ*BH*<WEM
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

It also isn't recognized as tar file by this library:
https://github.com/imagekit-developer/imagekit-ios/wiki/MimeType
`bytes[257...261] == [0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72]`

How can I find this archive's exact type and format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you search for is

```
uudecode attachment.tar
```

This will convert uuencoded tar file with name `RST.0486.20220814-0300.tar` from original file.

The usage of this format is to transfer via only ASCII-able "media" binary file.

Comment: After running `uudecode -i -o test2.tar  attachment.tar` it appeared to be a text file. So, it is not a TAR it is `text/x-uuencode`.

Comment: @mirik, UU format was popular 20 (or more) years a go, so it is understandable you did not recognize it. It was used mainly in Usenet groups for sending binary files :)

Answer (score 3):

The exact type and format is literally what `file` says – it's an UUEncoded file. This encoding used to be common on early networks before MIME/Base64 (i.e. before email had "attachments" as such).

UUEncode is only a transport format and the actual TAR archive is inside (similar to having TAR inside GZip). Use `uudecode` to convert the data back to binary format, and *then* you'll probably have a regular TAR archive. Linux has this program in the 'sharutils' package, while for Windows you can use UUDeview or UUDWin32.

Normally the mail client should've decoded the transport-encoding automatically, or at least saved the file as "attachment.tar.uu" (though I suppose there's no real convention for the latter).

Comment: The "begin" line gives the original Unix/Linux permission bits (644) for the chmod command followed by the original filename (both are optional, but permissions need to be specified if a filename is supplied). The lines starting with M all contain uu-encoded data and then the file ends with a single line starting with the word "end". There can be additional lines of plan text before "begin" and after "end". uudecode will ignore these. And it is possible to have multiple begin/end sections in the same file.